# find mapping link url and link text using php

Tags: php, url, mapping, data-extraction

this is my file and the contents of the file can change (just consider the format only not the exact wording for given in put file below)

```
i am <a href="link1">rohit</a>.So can any <a href="link2">body</a> help me regarding this.
```

from the above string i want mapping like a[0][0] = link1 and a[0][1] = rohit and a[1][0] = link2 and a[1][1] = body. this means in the file if text has href
then add in to the mapping array else leave the text. i want this solution using php so please help as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sub = 'i am <a href="link1">rohit</a>.So can any <a href="link2">body</a> help me regarding this. ';
preg_match_all('/<a href="(.+?)">(.+?)<\/a>/', $sub, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

// output
print_r($matches);


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a href="link1">rohit</a>
            [1] => link1
            [2] => rohit
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a href="link2">body</a>
            [1] => link2
            [2] => body
        )

)
```

Ref: [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)